# Reading chars from a pipe in C

Tags: c, char, pipe

This program reads the contents of a file and sends them over a pipe. I am having trouble reading from the pipe in the child process. The contents in my output file square characters. I think i must change c from an address to a value?

```
if (pid > 0) {  /* parent */
/* close the end of the pipe we do not need */
close(pfd[0]);

/* read from the input file and write to the pipe */
while ((c = getc(from)) != EOF){
    if (flipping){ 
        c = flipChar(c);
        write(pfd[1],&c, 1);
    }
    else
        write(pfd[1],&c, 1);

 }

  fclose(from);
  close(pfd[1]);

  wait(NULL);
 }
 else{  /* child process */

      close(pfd[1]);

      while (c = read(pfd[0],&c,1))
      {
      /* change c from a address to value?? */
      putc(c, destfile);
      }

      fclose(destfile);
      close(pfd[0]);
 }

 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: any error output? what is the nature of "having trouble?"

Answer (score 0):

[`read()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) returns the number of characters read.  so you execute `read(pfd[0], &c, 1)`, which stores a character in `c`, then immediately overwrite that character with a value of 1 (since you read a single character from the pipe).

Comment: So the read() function is something i shouldn't be using?. What should I change in my code so that the character I pass from the parent process is picked up in the child process?

Comment: you ARE picking up the character from your pipe.  You are calling `read()` properly, and you're storing something in `c`.  That's all good.  But after doing that, you proceed to overwrite the character you just stored because you're also taking the return code generated by `read()` (which is *not* the same as the character you read from a pipe) and dumping that into `c` too.

Comment: to put it another way:  why do you expect `read()` to return the next character from a pipe, given that you pass it a buffer in which to store things?  what do you expect the return value of `read()` to be if you wanted to read 2 or more characters at once?

Comment: So "&c" is my buffer in which the characters I want are stored? How do I take these from the buffer and print them to my file.

Comment: Thanks alot, after reading what you said more I managed to figure it out.